# installing my own Chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome Extension.  I had it successfully installed but then I uninstalled it.  Now I want to re-install it.  The directions say to simply drag the extension and drop it on the Chrome Extensions page.  I dragged and dropped the .json file onto the Extensions page.  I dropped it onto the button that said "Drop to Install".  When I dropped the file, the contents of the .json file opened as text in the Chrome tab.  It did not prompt me if I wanted to install.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to drag the .crx file, not the manifest

Comment: Thanks.  When I created the extension last year, I did not create a .crx file.  I only created a .json and a .js file.  Do I need to create a .crx file also?

Comment: OK, I packaged up the files in a .crx.  and now I was able to install

Comment: Better yet, you should load in as unpacked extension.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop a folder that contains all extension files.
Or pack it to the .crx file and drag and drop that file.